# grant permission for dbms_crypto

Tags: oracle, permissions, sql-grant, sysdba, dbms-crypto

I am using dbms_crypto.encrypt function in my oracle procedure for encryption of passwords. I have connected to oracle as :

```
connect sqlplus as sysdba
```

and then granted permission as :

```
grant execute on sys.dbms_crypto to myuser;
```

And then i can use dbms_crypto in my procedure. But i would like to know how can i check in my database whether the permission are granted or not for dbms_crypto ? Because i have to use this procedure in another database and does not know whether that database has grant permission or not for dbms_crypto.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get all the privileges on `DBMS_CRYPTO` with this:

```
select *
from dba_tab_privs
where table_name = 'DBMS_CRYPTO'
  and owner = 'SYS';
```

The result in your image says that `USER_ABCD` has the privilege to execute the package `SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO`, and this privilege has been given by `SYS` user.

Comment: please check my question i am getting the output as given in diagram. What does it mean ? Does it mean USER_ABCD has permission for dbms_crypto ?

Comment: ok and Does oracle have dbms_crypto grant permission by default when it is installed ?